# Loading CSS with Javascript Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, loading

I use this code below to load CSS files.

```
var i, a;
   for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++){
    if(a.getAttribute("title") == description){
        a.disabled = false;
        if(document.createStyleSheet) {
            try { document.createStyleSheet(a.href); } catch (e) {}
        }
        else {
        alert(a.href);
            var css;
            css         = document.createElement('link');
            css.rel     = 'stylesheet';
            css.type    = 'text/css';
            css.media   = "all";
            css.href    = a.href;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
        }
    }
    else if(a.getAttribute("title") != "default"){a.disabled = true;}
    }
```

Any reason why this should fail on Safari but works on IE, Chrome and Firefox??

Added:

I'm using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){dynamicLayout();})
        $(window).resize(function() {dynamicLayout();})
    </script>
```

to call dynamicLayout,

and when changing the width of the viewport (safari browser window) it just refuses to switch to the right css file. But works fine in mozilla/ie/chrome....

Sooo, don't know whats going on here. I always get trouble with jsfiddle for some reason, doesn't want to save and sometimes crashes my browser :-/ so sorry about that..

Hope this helps, if not just keep asking and I'll provide as much info as possible! =]

Comment: How is it failing? Have you looked in the developer tool's console log? Also, where is the `description` variable being set? A jsfiddle to see what is going on and experiment would be useful.

Comment: Just addes some extra lines to the question, hope that helps, if not, just keep asking havne't solved my problem yet, thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function dynamicLayout(){
var winWidth = $(window).width();
var winHeight = $(window).height();


changeLayout("default");

if (winWidth < 1148){
    changeLayout("thin");
}
if (winHeight < 810){
    changeLayout("tiny");
}
if ((winWidth < 1148) && (winHeight < 810)){
    changeLayout("thintiny");
}
```

}

function changeLayout(description){
   var i, a;

for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++){
        if(a.getAttribute("title") == description){

```
        a.disabled = false;
        if(document.createStyleSheet) {
            try {document.createStyleSheet(a.href); } catch (e) {}
        }

        else {

            var css;
            css         = document.createElement('link');
            css.rel     = 'stylesheet';
            css.type    = 'text/css';
            css.media   = "all";
            css.href    = a.href;
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
        }
    }

    else {
        if( (a.getAttribute("title") != "default") &&
            (a.getAttribute("title") != description)) {

            a.disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

}
}

Code above works great.

Turns out, Safari 5.something had a bug in it which made it impossible to insert css the way using script above. New version came out couple of days ago and now it's working fine =]..

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure why it isn't switching to the correct CSS file, but in my experience loading/changing CSS files can have a lot of quirks between browsers. IMO this is a much better solution for what it sounds like you are trying to do.

Basically I'm adding a class to the document body that says which width/size/aspect you want the page to use. Then in the CSS you just create multiple styles for few elements that need to change based on size/aspect/etc and prefix those styles with the CSS class they should use. Then you can use just one CSS file, and the transition will be more seamless.

### CSS

```
.wide #myDiv { width: 1000px; }
.tall #myDiv { width: 400px; }
```

### JavaScript

```
var updateLayout = function(){
    // logic for determining if the page is tall/wide or whatever your CSS selections criteria is based on
    if (wide) {
        $("body").addClass("wide").removeClass("tall");
    } else {
        $("body").addClass("tall").removeClass("wide");
    }
};

$(document).ready(updateLayout)
$(window).resize(updateLayout)
```

Comment: that's nice to remember. Great tip thnx! But I really need to load this using javascript. It's very strange Safari refuses to load files using javascript. Do you know anyone who might now the answer to this?

Comment: Why can't all of your styles be in one CSS file (even if it is loaded via JS), and then you switch between the sizes you want via CSS classes?

Comment: Well the thing is, using the method I'm using now, I can just add rules to thin.css, bitthinner.css, wide.css, bitwider.css, etc so that it only contains the code for adapting. It doesn't mess with the standard css file which makes it more easy to solve mistakes. atleast I find it more easy. But thats not the issue here. The issue is that safari isn't working. I'm not looking for another method to do what I want to do, but it's a nice tip anyway. So lets keep focused on the problem shall we ;-)

Comment: So you *have* to inject a new CSS file into the DOM via JS? It can't be `<link>`'d in the HTML, and that is the issue you are encountering with Safari?

Comment: No actualy safari had a bug, I've resolved it at this moment and will post the code soon for others to use.

Comment: Cool, I am interested to see what issue you were encountering and how you got around it.

Comment: Sure, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3215084?start=0&tstart=0 this is one of the links at the time I used to clearify what was going on. Seemed Safari had a bug in it from atleast aug'11 until about a week ago.

I got around it by just plainly f* ignoring it and I got lucky because it seems apple fixed it :-).

If apple wouldn't have I would just use the script they pointed at on that link to adapt my script. But my script works perfect, for me at least.

It just loads lines from css files which contain ONLY the rules needed to change the layout on * resolution.